# Changed field to Ngram, now returning no results

Tags: solr, n-gram

I updated my schema mapping for text fields to:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">              
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" axGramSize="15" side="front"/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">     
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>     
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

However, after doing this, and re-indexing the index, I get no search results at all for any query string. I only see results if I enter a `*` for the q parameter.

Is my schema mapping completely wrong, or am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo

```
axGramSize="15"
```

needs to be

```
maxGramSize="15"
```